# How do I install ionCube on an Azure Web Site?

Tags: php, azure, php-extension, azure-web-app-service, ioncube

I am trying to follow the instructions under [Using Custom PHP Extensions in Windows Azure Web Sites](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/silverlining/archive/2012/09/17/using-custom-php-extensions-in-windows-azure-web-sites.aspx) to enable the ionCube extension for PHP running within an Azure Web Site. Here's what I did:

1. Downloaded the Windows VC9 (Non-TS) (x86) loader from the [ionCube loader download page](http://www.ioncube.com/loaders.php).
2. Created a directory at /site/wwwroot/bin
3. FTP'd `ioncube_loader_win_5.3.dll` to that directory.
4. Under "app settings" in the Azure portal for the web site I added `PHP_EXTENSIONS` with value `bin/ioncube_loader_win_5.3.dll`.
5. I loaded http://my.azure.website/info.php and verified that the Environment table included `PHP_EXTENSIONS` = `bin/ioncube_loader_win_5.3.dll`. It also contains `APPSETTING_PHP_EXTENSIONS` = `bin/ioncube_loader_win_5.3.dll`.
6. When I try to load the site I get the message "The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred" and no additional information.

Is there something I forgot or is ioncube not supported on Azure? Did I set up the directory properly?

I also tried the Zend Guard Loader extension (ZendLoader.dll) in the same manner. I don't get an error message, but the extension doesn't show up in phpinfo() either.

Comment: I recently posted an answer around [ZendGuard on Windows Azure Web Sites](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15193837/how-can-i-enable-zend-guard-loader-extension-zendloader-dll-on-azure/17870774#17870774)

Comment: @SyntaxC4 Awesome ... if you create an answer to this question linking to your blog post I'll accept it as the answer to this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I posted an article explaining [How to configure ZendGuard on Windows Azure Web Sites](http://blog.syntaxc4.net/post/2013/07/25/enabling-zendguard-extension-in-windows-azure-web-sites.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You shall **not** put the module in the root of the ftp site. The DLL module **must** reside in a folder below the **APPLICATION ROOT**, which is `site/wwwroot/` So, you have to create either `site/wwwroot/bin` or anything of your choice (i.e. `site/wwwroot/phpext`), and then map PHP_EXTENSIONS again to `bin/ioncube...` (or `phpext/iocube...`), whatever is the name of your folder **underneath** `site/wwwroot/`!

However I am having trouble running any php page when the mentioned module is enabled. I don't know whether this is because my files are not ionCube encrypted, or because of some issue with the ionCube itself. So if you have a ionCube encrypted file, you have the chance to test.

Comment: I tried placing the file in all three locations, and only when I put it where you suggested (site/wwwroot/bit) did Azure seem to notice it at all. So I think you're correct about that. Unfortunately I had the same result as you ... the website won't even start now. Still looking for a solution.

Comment: the website starts, however the PHP is generating errors, which are most probably caused by the ionCube module, untraceable unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

ionCube is a Zend Extension, so according to an [answer on windows azure forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsazure/en-US/164345ef-bfdd-47ef-974c-45ccbc3fd17c/how-do-i-install-ioncube-on-an-azure-web-site?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview):

> The correct way to do it would be to create the **/site/wwwroot/bin** directory and upload **ioncube_loader_win_5.4.dll** there then add under the portal App Settings a **PHP_ZENDEXTENSIONS** setting with **bin\ioncube_loader_win_5.4.dll** as its value.

I confirm, but my tests was done in `/site/phpext` with an App Setting on `..\phpext\ioncube_loader_win_5.4.dll`.

Comment: While this may answer the question, it is better to provide the relevant portions of the answer here. Links break, and simply linking to off-site content does not make this site more valuable to users.