# I have a product (Kayoko) that runs on top Zend Optimizer, can it run on Windows Azure Web Sites?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, zend-optimizer

I bought a product called Kayoko and it runs on Zend Optimizer, my infrastructure in on Windows Azure Web Sites! Azure web sites says it runs on PHP 5.3 and 5.4! can it run on Windows Azure Web Sites?

Comment: I don't even understand the question, nor can I figure out if you're *excited* that Azure Web Sites has PHP 5.3/5.4 or *upset* about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you are talking about is [this](http://wiki.kayako.com/display/DOCS/Server+requirements). It clearly shows that it requires PHP 5.3. So you can run it, respecting the PHP version.

Now, the Zend optimizer is a bit tricky to run, but not impossible. Check out [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/silverlining/archive/2012/09/17/using-custom-php-extensions-in-windows-azure-web-sites.aspx) on how to configure third party PHP extensions. And [this StackOverflow question and my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13297801/how-do-i-install-ioncube-on-an-azure-web-site) on how to run IonCube which is similar to ZendOptimizer.

And please update your question to include concrete product names and appropriate links.